# How to compare two big text files without keeping both in memory

Tags: windows, perl, genetic

I am working on developing a genetic application. The user will select database file to search against.

The system should do:

1. find the previous version of the database file.
2. find differences between the 2 database files.
3. put the differences in a third file.
4. then perform the search against the new file (third one).

The database file is large (300 GB genomics data). I am using Windows as operating system, my application was written in js, PHP, Perl and HTML.

What is the best way to find the differences between those files?

Comment: Since the files are large, they cannot be loaded into memory. I think the best way would be to use the `rdiff` utility using PHP. Although, I'm not sure if the generated delta file would suit your purposes of step 4.

Comment: @user2570380: Is there an rdiff build for WIndows?

Comment: Are differences to be determined by a line-by-line comparison? If yes: where is the problem? If no: The way the files must be compared will dictate how to do it, and it needs to be known in order to find "the best way".

Comment: @Borodin No, Cygwin must be used.

Comment: @user2570380 Can you please expalin more about rdiff utility using PHP?

Comment: @user2570380 Do you mean diff utility of cygwin?

Comment: @Alaa: You can read more abour `rdiff` here: https://librsync.sourcefrog.net/rdiff.html. But you may also find answers to this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool-for-very-large-files